# Update URL without triggering state change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

My angular app uses UI Router.  I'm listening to state changes responding by scrolling to a different point. (its basically just a big parallax scroller)

So I can click menu links that take me to the correct places using the state machine, but if I want to scroll using the mousewheel, I'd like it to update the url as I scroll, but need to avoid the url change triggering an unnecessary state change.

How can I update the url to reflect the scroll position without triggering state change event etc?

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about preventing infinite loops in responding to events you caused. One solution is for your event handler to detect that it's already in the correct state for the given URL and do nothing

Comment: Yes, that's an option. I'll give it a try now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this did the trick in the end:

```
$state.go('STATE_NAME',null,{location:'replace',notify:false})
```

Comment: Nice: Many event systems allow this kind of _silent_ event.

Answer (score 0):

Angulajs has a html5 mode on its `$location` object which allows you to use the html5 history api for urls, here's the [angularjs docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) on it. You'd use this for linking to certain scroll locations.

Here is a good article here on using the [history api](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) outside of angularjs to change url without refreshing.

With this you could trigger with javascript (using the history api) the url change based on the scroll position/way points.

i.e. `if (scrollTop > 200) { changeUrl('some-url');} //Sudo code`

EDIT: As per the comments, this would NOT stop the router trying to process the newly changed url, so might not be right for all (and indeed this) situation.

Comment: I think the question is about how to prevent angular from responding to state changes that you caused yourself

Comment: You mean so the router doesn't try to process the url change, I see. If that is the case then yes the above wouldn't be right

Comment: Juan is right. I need to prevent the router feeding back

Comment: Have edited the answer to show it not quite right, but left it up in case it helps anyone else